Problem in vector dot product "factorisation"
Problem: Let $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ be $3$ non-collinear vectors in $R^3$ satisfying:
$$\dfrac{\vec{a}.\vec{b}}{\vec{b}.\vec{b}}=\dfrac{\vec{a}.\vec{c}}{\vec{b}.\vec{c}}$$
Suppose $\vec{a}=\alpha \vec{b}+\beta\vec{c}+\gamma (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})$. Then determine the value of $\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{\gamma}$.
My attempt:
$(\vec{a}.\vec{b})(\vec{b}.\vec{c})-(\vec{a}.\vec{c})(\vec{b}.\vec{b})=0$ ...(i)
$\implies \vec{a}.[(\vec{b}.\vec{c})\vec{b}-(\vec{b}.\vec{b})\vec{c}]=0$
Recognising the vector triple product expression for $\vec{b} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})$ in the square braces, this can be rewritten as;
$\vec{a}.\vec{b} \times (\vec{b} \times \vec{c})=0 \implies (\vec{a} \times \vec{b}).(\vec{b} \times \vec{c})=0$ using the property of the scalar triple product.
This statement implies that the normal of the plane containing $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is perpendicular to the normal of the plane containing $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ i.e. the planes themselves are perpendicular. Hence, $\vec{a}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{c}$ i.e. $\vec{a}.\vec{c}=0$. Substituting this in (i), either $\vec{a}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{b}$ or $\vec{b}.\vec{c}=0$. However, the second case is impossible since it will make the denominator of the RHS $0$ in the original equation. Thus, $\vec{a}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{b}$ i.e. it bears no component in the direction of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, being in the direction normal to the plane containing $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ (i.e. along $\vec{b} \times \vec{c})$. Accordingly, $\alpha=\beta=0, \gamma \neq 0$
I was quite surprised that we can deduce so much from such a simple relation in the ratio of dot products of these vectors. The step I'm having some trouble convincing myself with is the one in which I factored out the $\vec{a}$ in the dot product while there were other dot products multiplied with it. Is that a legal step? I haven't ever done anything like it before, hence it seems fishy to me.
